# The output of the functionality isn't corresponding with the intended result

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I wanted to add a functionality whereby if the final score of the match is equal to the predicted score, the trailing text should be "Won" with green colour, else it should be "Lost" with red colour. But then I'm not getting the logic right, no matter the outcome, the trailing text shows lost.

This is the code below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyListTile({
    Key? key,
    required this.homeTeamName,
    required this.awayTeamName,
    required this.scoreFulltime,
    required this.oddsString,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String homeTeamName;
  final String awayTeamName;
  final String scoreFulltime;
  final String oddsString;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final predictedScore = oddsString.split(' ')[0];
    final hasWon = scoreFulltime == predictedScore;

    return ListTile(
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        child: Text(homeTeamName[0]),
      ),
      contentPadding:
      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 20.0),
      title: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
        child: Text(
          '$homeTeamName vs $awayTeamName',
          style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 22),
        ),
      ),
      subtitle: RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          text: 'Score:',
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
          ),
          children: <TextSpan>[
            TextSpan(
              text: ' $scoreFulltime  ',
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
            ),
            const TextSpan(
              text: '   Prediction:',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent),
            ),
            TextSpan(
              text: ' $oddsString',
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      trailing: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 4),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          color: hasWon ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
        ),
        child: Text(
          hasWon ? 'Won' : 'Lost',
          style: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Screenshot of the scores screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP2rG.png)

This is the listview builder of MyListTile

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../tips_widget.dart';

ListView myListBuilder(List<Map<String, dynamic>> tips) {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: tips.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      final tip = tips[index];
      final homeTeamName = tip['team1'];
      final awayTeamName = tip['team2'];
      final scoreFulltime = tip['score_fulltime'];
      final bettingTips = tip['betting_tips'];

      final odds = <String>[];
      bettingTips.forEach((key, value) {
        odds.add(value['odds']);
      });
      final oddsString = odds.join(' / ');

      return MyListTile(
          homeTeamName: homeTeamName,
          awayTeamName: awayTeamName,
          scoreFulltime: scoreFulltime,
          oddsString: oddsString,

      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey, what does the `oddsString` look like? And also the `scoreFulltime ` String?

Comment: Yeah, they are String.

Comment: Yes but how are they supposed to look like (could you give me an example?)

Comment: So is the scoreFulltime looking like that: 0/1 ? or like 1 or like 0:1 ?
And the oddsString? like 0 / 1 ??

Comment: I attached a screenshot there along with the code.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP2rG.png I wanted a situation whereby if the score and the prediction is the same, the trailing text should change to green with the word Won, but then, it's not working. I am getting the Lost trailing text no matter the result.\

Comment: the score fulltime is 0:1 and the oddstring is 0:1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try this:

```
final hasWon = scoreFulltime == oddsString.replaceAll(“-”,”:”);
```

Comment: Now in some screens, the oddsString will be a text like Draw or Both Team Score, How can I make it like if the first number or letter is the same, it should return win?

Comment: I mean it doesn’t really make sense to have the oddsString formatted differently on every screen. (And if you just compare the first number it doesn’t really compare properly right?) I personally would create a Map or custom class that contains the data for example {“teamA”: 4, “teamB”:2} and then from there would do all the comparisons etc. and then you could also do something like if(map[“teamA] == map[teamB]){bool draw = true}

Comment: So just a clear and consistent data structure you can use troughout the app

Comment: Okay to consolidate my thougths: I'd create a custom MatchResults Class that has the following fields: team1Name, team2Name, team1FinalScore?, team2FinalScore?, team1PredictedScore, team2PredictedScore    And then you just have to keep a List<MatchResults> in your App with all the MatchResults. Form that you can do all the stuff you want to do. You could add a method to the class that returns win, draw or lost strings or stuff like that.

Comment: Okay to consolidate my thougths: I'd create a custom MatchResults Class that has the following fields: team1Name, team2Name, team1FinalScore?, team2FinalScore?, team1PredictedScore, team2PredictedScore    And then you just have to keep a List<MatchResults> in your App with all the MatchResults. Form that you can do all the stuff you want to do. You could add a method to the class that returns win, draw or lost strings or stuff like that.

Comment: Thank you, I'll do that.

Comment: Please can you checkout this question for me and see if you know how I can fix this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/75922026/19589068

Comment: Sorry I only worked with firestore yet, so I don't really have any Idea whats wrong..

GPT4 thinks the following would help, but I have no Idea :/ But I am sure you'll find the solution (maybe look into the documentation again to see if theres anything done differently?)


`final tips = <Map<String, dynamic>>[];

final Map data = dataSnapshot.value as Map;

data.forEach((key, value) {
  final categoryMap = (value as Map).cast<String, dynamic>();
  categoryMap.forEach((key, value) {
    tips.add((value as Map).cast<String, dynamic>());
  });
});`